# How can I sum up numbers from file without adding the dates which are within the file?

Tags: python, regex

am trying to sum up the numbers from a file using regex, which contains dates, names and numbers,
but I cant get to sum the particular numbers without adding the dates too.
Example of file contents:

```
2/3/21 steve 500
4/4/21 john 300
```

QN. HOW DO I GET THE SUM OF 500 AND 300 WITHOUT ADDING THE DATES.

Comment: Does the number always ends the line ?

Comment: yes numbers to sum are at the end of the line

Comment: Is something preventing you from just splitting the string on the last space?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is well formatted, and the number is always at the end of the line, just use `str.split`

```py
# file content
2/3/21 steve 500
4/4/21 john 300
# ------------------------
with open("file.txt") as f:
    total = sum(int(row.split()[-1]) for row in f.read().splitlines())
```

If the file may contain lines without numbers, or some non-digit content after the value, you use the regex `"(\d+)\D*$"` that will take the last nnumber from a row

```py
# file content
2/3/21 steve 500
4/4/21 john 300 word
no number
2/3/21 steve 500
# ------------------------
import re
with open("file.txt") as f:
    total = sum(map(int, re.findall(r"(\d+)\D*$", f.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the data is formatted like the example you gave, you could use this:

```py
total = 0

with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        total += int(line.strip().split()[-1])

print(total)
```